# Magento Connect Manager installation not working

Tags: magento-connect, extensions, m2e

Logging into the Magento Connect Manager, I've added the Extension Key from Magento Connect, and clicked "Install". For 0.2-0.5 Seconds, the "Please Wait" box flashes up then promptly disappears.

Nothing else happens at all. It happens whichever extension I try to install.

Very odd.

The store is v. 1.8.1.0 installed on CentOS

Could any body shine any light upon this at all, or suggest where I might look for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some of the files might be missing from the `downloader` folder. Please copy the `downloader` folder from the fresh magento1.8 folder structure and replace it on your website.

Once done, check for the files and folder permissions. It should work for you. Please keep the backup of the old folder though.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Magento requirements check to make sure that you aren't missing anything:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

Comment: Thanks for this, checked it and (un)fortunately it all looks fine - the site is installed and running fine, it really is just that it's refusing to accept any more extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You might got some error like that or saying "The connection string is empty" what you can do is check permission of files & folder inside magento.

Comment: Just temporarily changed permissions to 0777; alas no luck, still not doing anything... Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with Magento 1.9.1, when extension was downloaded, but not installed.

No permission or other setting I found on net helped, but copying the downloader files from fresh Magento installation fixed the problem, as Dexter mentioned for 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same problem i did clear the cache and things were fine. it started to work. a cache file was creating this error. Hope it works for you.